# Why am I getting Ruby segmentation faults with thrubyracer gem?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-ec2, therubyracer

I have a production instance of our application in AWS EC2. My team develops locally on Fedora 18. Recently, when pushing our code to production, we noticed that we were getting segmentation faults when running'rake assets:precompile' or 'script/delayed_job start|stop'. These work fine on our development machines.

In attempts to isolate the problem, we upgraded RBENV from 1.9.3-p327 to RBENV 1.9.3-p385. Then, to try and isolate RBENV, I created a new user, 'testuser', and a clean install of RVM with 1.9.3-p385. Same problems.

The segfault detail seems to point to 'therubyracer' gem. I can not find any information that looks like our problem.

```
    gem install minitest
    WARNING!! No private key specified, gem will not be signed!
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/therubyracer-0.11.3/lib/v8/init.so: [BUG] Segmentation fault
    ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-linux]

    -- Control frame information -----------------------------------------------
   <snip>
    -- Ruby level backtrace information ----------------------------------------
    script/delayed_job:3:in `<main>'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    /home/testuser/apps/pharos/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    /home/testuser/apps/pharos/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler.rb:128:in `require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:55:in `each'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `block in require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:66:in `each'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `block (2 levels) in require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/bundler-1.2.4/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:68:in `require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs.rb:5:in `<module:ExecJS>'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:50:in `autodetect'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:56:in `best_available'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:56:in `find'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/runtimes.rb:56:in `each'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/execjs-1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:99:in `available?'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/therubyracer-0.11.3/lib/v8.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    /home/testuser/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385/gems/activesupport-3.2.11/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'

<snip>

    [NOTE]
    You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
    Bug reports are welcome.
    For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

Comment: What section would you like to see? SO won't let me paste the whole thing; too many characters several times over.

Comment: The contents of the log file referenced under *C level backtrace information* would be interesting. If it's too long, put it in a gist or so.